# How can I connect 2 users payment directly?

Tags: paypal

For example I have a website on which there is a seller and a buyer. Is it possible for the buyer to pay directly to the seller(not through me)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the link between a payment button and the Paypal account that will receive the funds, we use the e-mail address of the seller's Paypal account.
For example if you have payment buttons on your website and you want the money to go to the seller's directly, you can use the e-mail address of the specific seller's Paypal account in each buttons.
Feel free to contact us via https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/ if you need further help

Regards,
Florian

Comment: In that case, is it possible for me to track buyer to seller payments?